# Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `show`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap-table

I created a bootstrap-table, that onClick of the row, a modal pops-up showing an information of items in the row. This works fine, but when I click on the row, the browser's console shows this error.

Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `show`. If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: show="true" or show={value.toString()}.

These are my codes

useState and const

```
        const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);
        const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(null);

        const [modalInfo, setModalInfo] = useState({
        id: '',
        name: '',
        stock: number,
        stockLevelDate: Date,
        tankThreatLevel: number,
        tankThreatLevelColor: '',
        tankTopPosition: number,
        tankTopPositionColor: '',
        lowPumpable: number,
        lowPumpableColor: '',
        tankCapacity: number,
       });

       const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
       const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
       const toggleTrueFalse = () => setShowModal(handleShow);
```

buttton calling the Modal

```
       <div className="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
          <Button color="body" size="sm" onClick={() => handleShow()}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline"></span>
          </Button>
        </div>
```

The files are in .tsx

I tried setting the boolean values to strings, but it results in abnormality of the modal, whereby closing the modal does not work

jsx for modal

```
   const ModalContent = () => {
   return (
    <>
    <Modal isOpen show={show}>
      <ModalHeader>Terminal Info</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        <ul>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>id : {modalInfo.id}</h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>Name : {modalInfo.name} 
         </h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>Stock : 
        {modalInfo.stock}</h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>Stock-Level-Date : 
        {modalInfo.stockLevelDate}</h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>Tank-Threat-Level : 
         {modalInfo.tankThreatLevel}</h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>Tank-Threat-Level-Color 
         : {modalInfo.tankThreatLevelColor}</h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>tank-Top-Position : 
         {modalInfo.tankTopPosition}</h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>Low-Pumpable : 
        {modalInfo.lowPumpable}</h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>Low-Pumpable-Color : 
        {modalInfo.lowPumpableColor}</h6>
          <h6 style={{ fontFamily: 'Georgia' }}>Tank Capacity : 
       {modalInfo.tankCapacity}</h6>
        </ul>
       </ModalBody>
       <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="ban" />
          &nbsp; Close
        </Button>
       </ModalFooter>
       </Modal>
       </>
       );
     };
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the modal also?

Comment: @shehanpathirathna This is react, there is no HTML

Comment: Shehan probably meant jsx